# CodeIgniter + Smarty - is it relevant?

Tags: codeigniter, templates, smarty

I'm starting a new website, using CodeIgniter for the first time. In the views, there is PHP code written. I was thinking of completely separate the code from display, as I did few years ago using Smarty.

I found a template engine provided by CodeIgniter : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html

But inside of the page, I found this note :

> > Note: CodeIgniter does not require you to use this class since using pure PHP in your view pages lets them run a little faster. However, some developers prefer to use a template engine if they work with designers who they feel would find some confusion working with PHP.

So, I wanted some help to choose the right thing. Should I use pure PHP ? What would be the advantage of using a template engine like this one, when the coding style is already MVC ? Would it be better to use Smarty, that I already know a little ?

The website will need to be very secure AND very fast, a lot of AJAX will be used (I was thinking to install a websocket as well, but there is no link to the current question).

Thanks for your help !

Comment: In general, it's good to separate concerns by using a templating system, and not having random PHP mixed with HTML printing. The chances that the templating engine is the bottleneck in your application is quite low.

Comment: So you would recommend to use one, either native CI one or Smarty ?

Comment: CI's template parser isn't comparable to Smarty, they are totally different. In any case, use whatever you want.

Comment: Totally different, but the goal is the same, taking out PHP code from the display, am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require your application to be fast, then you've been quite inspired in choosing Codeigniter, as it's a very lightweight framework and it's going to solve most speed concerns quite easily, when caching isn't involved.

There's a saying that you shouldn't scale unless you need to, and I think that it applies very well here. Unless you're displaying megabytes of data, I don't see how choosing a templating engine might harm the overall speed of your application. In the event that it does happen, you can always have a look at caching some responses/various other bits of information or third party solutions (i.e. Gearman) which may be overkill for now.

If you want to learn something new, go with the Codeigniter templating library; if you need to develop something fast, use the tools that you know best. As a matter of preference, I love Twig, and there is a CI implementation for it, called Twiggy: http://edmundask.github.io/codeigniter-twiggy/

As for security, I'd say it's not as robust as an enterprise level framework, like Symfony or ZF2, which place higher emphasis on that. They are more complete packages in themselves, and with caching, they perform super-fast, but they come with a higher learning curve.

**Update:** What I meant by the the idea that unless you're displaying huge amounts of data you shouldn't consider the speed of templating engines is that there will be a negligible effect on your page rendering speed. Don't imagine that it's something that a user would ever notice, as the order of 0.0x in execution time isn't noticeable. Take a look here for a comparison between SMARTY and Twig: http://umumble.com/blogs/php/249/

0.058 seconds of execution time for Smarty vs. 0.083 seconds of execution time for Twig. Templating engines always carry an overhead, their facility is that they make development easier, and it helps out when working with designers.

Comment: Thanks for this answer ! Very clear. Just one thing you didn't answered to : why bother to use a template engine here without any caching while CI's documentation says it just would go slower ?

about the security, well I will have to code carefully, I guess  :)

Comment: @JeremyBelolo Hey man, updated my answer. Let me know if it's clearer now!

Comment: Thanks, actually yes it's clearer. I think I will go with Twig !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with a templating engine, I suggest Twig.  http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: What does it have that would be better than Smarty or CI's native solution ?

Comment: CI's native solution is just PHP, which isn't a solution at all if you want to use a templating engine. :)

Twig is maintained by SensioLabs -- creators of Symfony.  It's highly respected, easy to use, and very fast.  As a personal preference, I prefer Twig syntax to Smarty's.